# passing a 2D array to a function and multiplying it by two

Tags: c++, c++11

I Am trying to pass this array and then multiply it by 2. My code works, but it multiples it by 4 instead I think its because of the for loop inside another for loop. Can someone explain how to fix this?

5x5 array:

```
int numbers  [5][5] = { {  1,    3,    5,    7,    9},
                        { -2,   -4,   -6,   -8,  -10},
                        {  3,    3,    3,    3,    3},
                        { 55,   77,   99,   22,   33},
                        {-15, -250, -350, -450, -550} };

// function
int multiply_bytwo(int n[5][5])
{
    int total_times = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            n[row][col] = n[row][col] * 2;
        }

        return total_times;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return total_times;` bails out your loop early.

Comment: ***but it multiples it by 4 instead***... how do you know that???

Comment: Please edit your question and give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  so when i moved return total_times nothing changed except that now everything is multiplied by 4. instead of 2

Comment: @CowboyCoder can you explain how do you know that your 2-D array is multiplied by 4 instead of 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made your code into a MCV example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// function
int multiply_bytwo(int n[5][5])
{
    int total_times = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            n[row][col] = n[row][col] * 2;
            printf("%d\n", n[row][col]);
        }
        return total_times;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numbers  [5][5] = { { 1,3,5,7,9},{-2,-4,-6, -8, -10},{3,3,3,3,3},{ 55, 77, 99, 22, 33 },{ -15, -250, -350, -450, -550 } };
    multiply_bytwo(numbers);
}
```

also, note the added `printf()` calls this is outputting the calculated values when they are generated.

Output:

```
$ gcc temp.c -std=c99 && ./a.exe

2  6  10  14  18
```

What are we seeing here?  Well, the first row is being multiplied by 2 (`{1,3,5,7,9}` -> `{2,6,10,14,18}`) and then the function is exiting.

What is the result when we move the return statement out of the loop?

code:

```
int multiply_bytwo(int n[5][5])
{
    int total_times = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++){
        printf("\n");
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++){
            n[row][col] = n[row][col] * 2;
            printf("%d  ", n[row][col]);
        }
    }
    return total_times;
}
```

result:

```
  2    6   10   14    18
 -4   -8  -12  -16   -20
  6    6    6    6     6
110  154  198   44    66
-30 -500 -700 -900 -1100
```

I took the liberty of manually aligning the output, but the numbers are exactly as you want.

I don't know where you got the `*4` from.

You also don't actually return anything - you set `total_times = 0` at the beginning and never modify it.  you probably meant to increment it when performing the multiplication.

Comment: Thank you! my full program had a menu (do loop) and i did not notice i forgot a break in one of the options. it works now.

Comment: @CowboyCoder if it helped you , feel free to upvote.  If it is the most useful answer, please accept.

Comment: i did but since my rep is not high enough my vote doesnt show. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `return total_times` does nothing but return 0, 
I'm assuming you wanted to get a count of how many times the loop ran, that would be done using `total_times++;`

Moving the return out side of your loops makes the function return the final desired array

I would recommend adding prints in many locations for problems like this so that you can debug the issue as you go such as :

```
expected = VALUE
actual = VALUE
```

This should help you find where you've gone wrong.

```
int numbers  [5][5] = { {  1 ,  3,   5,   7,   9},
                        { -2,  -4,  -6,  -8, -10},
                        {  3,   3,   3,   3,   3},
                        { 55,  77,  99,  22,  33},
                        {-15,-250,-350,-450,-550} 
                      };



// function
int multiply_bytwo(int n[5][5])
{

    int total_times = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {


        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            n[row][col] = n[row][col] * 2;
            total_times ++;
        }


    }
   return total_times;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// function
int multiply_bytwo(int n[5][5])
{

    int total_times = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            n[row][col] = n[row][col] * 2;
            total_times++;
        }
    }

    return total_times;
}
```